# Creating New Webservice with Available methods in DLL

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a solution file ( i.e DLL file). i want to create webservice/WCF Service which exposes  the methods  of DLL file. so that other team can use webservice instead of DLL reference

simply we cannot Add DLL as a reference to another project because another project is using  in java..
so i have been provided DLL file and asked me to create one webservice( WCF is also fine) by using  DLL file related methods.

please help me  and my question is how can i expose DLL methods in Newly created webservice?

webservice/wcf any thing should be fine .

Comment: Can you modify this DLL? There are ways to automatically create web services from existing classes, but you typically need to decorate the methods with attributes to tell the web service code what is what.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Yes i can modify the DLL . can you point me some links how to automatically create the web service from existing class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a WCF Service, which has reference to this DLL file, You can call the  functions in DLL from Operation contract() in your service contract.

And these operation contracts can be called from your other java project.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can!

If you can't edit the DLL:

Just create a normal webservice solution, and create the web methods that you want to expose in the DLL.

Then just call the appropriate DLL method in each web method.

If you can edit the DLL, just turn the project into a webservice project and expose the appropriate methods

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes i can edit DLL( i have solution file ) but could you please tell me how can i turn the project into web service project in .net ?  how can i automatically convert Project into WebService project ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This Beginners [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows) is excellent and should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose all dlls from the WebService Application. Add reference to WebService project

```
[WebMethod]
public bool CheckLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            bool status = false;

            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
            try
            {
               Command.CommandText="Select count(*) from CM_Users where username='"+username+"' and passwd='"+password+"'";
               Command.Connection=DbConnection.OpenDbConnection();
                  // this is Assembly Loaded from Application

               int count=(int)Command.ExecuteScalar();

                if(count>0)
                    status=true;
                else
                    status=false;

                DbConnection.CloseDbConnection(Command.Connection);

            }
            catch (SqlException expmsg)
            {
                DbConnection.CloseDbConnection(Command.Connection);

            }


            return status;

        }
```